# Initialize Array after ReDim

Tags: arrays, vb.net, initialization

Is there a better way to do this?  I do not need to preserve the data in the array.

```
ReDim Test(4)
For i = 0 to Test.Count()-1
    Test(i) = New MyObject
Next
```

Comment: [Pick your poison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/).

Comment: One alternative would be the GetUpperBound \ GetLowerBound functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for

```
test = Enumerable.Repeat(New MyObject, 4)
```

EDIT:
That was not what I was looking as it just creates same object.  This is what I was looking for.

```
test = Enumerable.Range(1,4).Select(Function(i) New MyObject()).ToArray
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fill your array as shown below the `ReDim` is not necessary.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Test1() As Integer
    Test1 = {0, 1, 2, 3}
    For Each i In Test1
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
    Dim Test2() As Coffee
    'I have a Coffee class with a parameterized constructor
    Test2 = {New Coffee("Folgers", 0), New Coffee("Pete's", 1), New Coffee("Tully's", 2), New Coffee("Green Mountain", 3)}
    For Each c In Test2
        Debug.Print(c.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```